# How to manual reinstall Windows XP Telephony service (TapiSrv) that fails to start with Event ID 7023 (cannot find file specified)?

Tags: windows-xp, services

After using the XPlite tool the Windows Telephony service is no longer installed on our Windows XP Professional SP3 installation.

I was partly successful in manually reinstall the missing Telephony service, by:

1. retrieve the missing TapiSrv.dll file from http://originaldll.com/file/tapisrv.dll/2345.html
2. recreate the service with the command `sc create TapiSrv binpath= "C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs" type= share displayname= "Telephony" error= normal start= demand depend= "PlugPlay/RpcSs"`

A manual start of the "Telephony" service fails with **Event ID 7023**:

> The Telephony service terminated with the following error: 
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

How can I start the Windows XP Telephony service again without re-installing the OS or restore from a backup?

Comment: -1 for modifying Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding this registry key to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TapiSrv\Parameters` with name `ServiceDll` of type "*expandable string value*" (`REG_EXPAND_SZ`) and value `%SystemRoot%\System32\tapisrv.dll`, the "*Telephony*" service is able to start.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TapiSrv\Parameters]
"ServiceDll"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,\
  00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,\
  74,00,61,00,70,00,69,00,73,00,72,00,76,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,00,00
```